# Bison Flex compiler returning "y.tab.h" file not found error

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

Im trying to build a syntactic analyzer using Bison and Flex. I have the following .y / .l files:

SintBis.y

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
%}

%token P_RESERVADA
%token OPERADOR
%token A_LLAVE
%token C_LLAVE
%token A_PARENTESIS
%token C_PARENTESIS
%token A_CORCHETE
%token C_CORCHETE
%token FIN_SENTENCIA
%token TIPO_DATO
%token SIMBOLOS
%token P_FOR
%token P_DEFINE
%token P_RETURN
%token DIGITO
%token LETRA
%token P_INCREMENTO
%token P_DECREMENTO


%token NUMERO
%token S_COMA
%token S_MENOR
%token S_MAYOR
%token S_IGUAL
%token S_NUMERAL
%token LIBRERIAS
%start INICIO
%% 
    INICIO: INCLUDES FUNCION_PRINCIPAL;

    INCLUDES: S_NUMERAL P_RESERVADA S_MENOR LIBRERIAS S_MAYOR|S_NUMERAL P_DEFINE LETRA NUMERO;

    FUNCION_PRINCIPAL: TIPO_DATO P_RESERVADA A_PARENTESIS C_PARENTESIS A_LLAVE EXPRESIONES C_LLAVE;

    EXPRESIONES: DECLARACIONES_VARIABLES BUCLE_FOR P_RETURN NUMERO;

    DECLARACIONES_VARIABLES: VARIABLE | VARIABLE DECLARACIONES_VARIABLES;

    VARIABLE: TIPO_DATO LETRA A_CORCHETE NUMERO C_CORCHETE S_COMA LETRA A_CORCHETE LETRA C_CORCHETE FIN_SENTENCIA
            | TIPO_DATO LETRA S_COMA  LETRA S_COMA LETRA S_IGUAL NUMERO FIN_SENTENCIA;

    BUCLE_FOR: P_FOR A_PARENTESIS LETRA S_IGUAL NUMERO FIN_SENTENCIA LETRA S_MAYOR FIN_SENTENCIA LETRA P_INCREMENTO C_PARENTESIS A_LLAVE 
        LETRA S_IGUAL LETRA OPERADOR NUMERO FIN_SENTENCIA
        LETRA A_CORCHETE LETRA C_CORCHETE S_IGUAL LETRA FIN_SENTENCIA
        LETRA S_IGUAL LETRA OPERADOR LETRA FIN_SENTENCIA
        C_LLAVE;

%%
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    extern FILE *yyin;
    yyin = fopen("argv[1]", "rt");
    if(yyin == NULL)
        printf("\nNo se puede leer el archivo seleccionado");

    if(yyparse()==0)
    printf("\nAnalisis concluido sin errores\n");
    fclose(yyin);
    getch();
}
yyerror(char* mensaje){
    printf("\nAnalisis suspendido");
    printf("\nMensaje: %s",mensaje);
}
```

SintLex.l:

```
%option noyywrap
%{
    #include "y.tab.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
%}
DIGITO [0-9]+
LETRA  [a-zA-Z]+
%%
"include"|"Include"|"INCLUDE"|"main"|"MAIN"|"Main"|"VOID"|"void"|"Void"|"printf"|"scanf"        {return P_RESERVADA;}
"define"|"DEFINE"                                           {return P_DEFINE;}
"return"|"Return"|"RETURN"                                      {return P_RETURN;}
"+"|"-"|"*"|"/"                                             {return OPERADOR;}
"++"                                                    {return P_INCREMENTO;}
"--"                                                    {return P_DECREMENTO;}
"{"                                                 {return A_LLAVE;}
"}"                                                 {return C_LLAVE;}
"("                                                 {return A_PARENTESIS;}
")"                                                 {return C_PARENTESIS;}
"]"                                                 {return C_CORCHETE;}
"["                                                 {return A_CORCHETE;}
";"                                                 {return FIN_SENTENCIA;}
"int"|"double"                                              {return TIPO_DATO;}
"#"                                                 {return S_NUMERAL;}
"<"                                                 {return S_MENOR;}
">"                                                 {return S_MAYOR;}
","                                                 {return S_COMA;}
"="                                                 {return S_IGUAL;}
"for"                                                   {return P_FOR;}
"stdio.h"|"STDIO.H"|"STDLIB.H"|"stdlib.h"|"STRING.H"|"string.H"                     {return LIBRERIAS;}
{DIGITO}                                                {return DIGITO;}
{LETRA}                                             {return LETRA;}
```

The compiling procedure i'm following is: first the bison file using `bison -d -o AnalizadorSintactico.c SintBis.y` 
then the flex file using `flex -o AnalizadorSintacticoLex.c SintLex.l`

I am obtaining from these two steps the files **AnalizadorSintactico.c**, **AnalizadorSintactico.h** and **AnalizadorSintacticoLex.c**

When i execute the command 
`gcc AnalizadorSintactico.c AnalizadorSintacticoLex.c -lfl -o compilador` 
it returns the following error `SintLex.l:3:11: fatal error: 'y.tab.h' file not found
        #include "y.tab.h"`

Is the last step incorrect? Am i missing something?

I have tried different sintaxis for the last step but i am always obtaining that error. I have also tried following the advice of similar questions asked here but with no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You included `y.tab.h` in your lexer but Bison generated `AnalizadorSintactico.h`.  Are you surprised the compiler complained?

Use `#include "AnalizadorSintactico.h"` instead of `#include "y.tab.h"`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, bison writes its output to basename.tab.h and basename.tab.c when compiling basename.y.  You can change that with the `-o` option to anything else you want (as you've done).  Or you can use the `-y` flag to emulate yacc and write to y.tab.c and y.tab.h